# Увлекаются ли туризмом?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Можно ли сказать "Она увлекается туризмом"? Мне не очень нравится такой оборот.

Answer (score 1):

Да, так вполне грамотно говорить.

[**увлека́ться**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/5508/%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)
*глаг., нсв., употр. сравн. часто*
Морфология: я увлека́юсь, ты увлека́ешься, он/она/оно увлека́ется…
1. Если вы увлекаетесь чем-либо, то это означает, что вы с интересом чем-либо занимаетесь, что-либо изучаете.
**Увлекаться театром, музыкой, спортом.** | Увлекаться импрессионизмом. | Подростком Валентин начал увлекаться философией и психологией.

*Еще эта интеллигенция увлекалась туризмом, водными походами, как бы стараясь уйти от повседневной суеты, слиться с природой* (А. Атеев);
Е*сли чем и увлекалась, так туризмом и спортивным ориентированием* (М. Ахманов).

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, вполне легитимно. Можно увлекаться любым спортом, любым видом деятельности, и туризм не исключение. В подтверждение — цитата из Нацкорпуса:

> Борька только что женился тогда, но всего первые два или три лета молодые и жили на даче, а потом начали каждый отпуск ездить то на юг, то на Байкал ― **увлекались туризмом**, пока сына не родили, а сын у них появился поздно, через десять лет после женитьбы. [Нина Катерли. Дорога (1981)]

Answer (score 0):

Так *можно* сказать об одном из аспектов туризма (хождение в походы) или формально о систематическом пользовании услугами туристических фирм, организующих поездки ("*туры*"); для них все клиенты - *туристы*, а область деятельности таких фирм - *туризм*. Если персонаж действует в таких поездках самостоятельно (не услуги потребляет) и не проводит в них всё время на пляже, то правильнее сказать "**любит путешествовать**".

Comment: ТУРИЗМ, -а; м. [франц. tourisme] 1. Вид спорта - групповые походы в необжитые места с целью повышения выносливости организма. Горный, автомобильный, пешеходный т. **Увлекаться туризмом**. Экстремальный т. (предполагающий высокие физические нагрузки). 2. Вид путешествий, в которых отдых сочетается с познавательной, культурной, спортивной целью. Внутренний, международный т. Самодеятельный, организованный т. Этнографический т. <Туристический; Туристский (см.). (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)

Comment: Вопрос сводится к тому, чем туризм отличается от путешествий.

Comment: Думаю, что отличается ограниченностью маршрута (пешего, на животных или лодках). Путешествия и международный туризм до открытия границ были недоступны, под ними подразумевались кинопутешествия и приезд иностранцев, с которыми не дай бой пообщаться :) Поэтому изначально в языке под туризмом подразумевались "походы" и маршруты, организуемые вдали по "путевкам", который в свободной продаже не было. С изменением реальности появились и неоднозначности в языке (туризм - это или походы, или организованные загранпоездки).